# Need Help to find id of dynamically created input control in the press event of value help in sap ui5

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I am new to SAP UI5 and fiori , I have created one UI5 application with functionality to add new Input field dynamically on the click of a button and I have attached the value help request with the Input field. 
For the value help I am using `sap.m.SelectDialog`.
Now how to get the ID of input control in the confirm even of Select Dialog. 
I tried using `oEvent.getSource()` in confirm event but it did not work. 
pls help...

Comment: Please, could you share some code? Relavant view and controller snippets should be good

Comment: Issue resolved by using fiori local storage

Answer (score 0):

You can try either below, depend on which type of rows/items using in your binding

It will return the value in the input field

```js
// 1
var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
var oBarContent = oSource.getContent();
var oToolBarContent = oBarContent[0].getContent();
var oSearch = oToolBarContent[1];
var sQuery = oSearch.getValue().toUpperCase();

// 2
var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");
```